# pandas series how to fill na with last valid value

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a panda series that I want to fill the last value that is not nan. For example,

```
a=pd.Series({1: 1918,  2: 1928, 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan, 5: np.nan, 6: 1853, 7: 1831})
Out[113]: 
1    1918
2    1928
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     NaN
6    1853
7    1831
dtype: float64
```

What I want is the following:

```
a=pd.Series({1: 1918,
2: 1928,
3: np.nan,
4: np.nan,
5: 1928,
6: 1853,
7: 1831})
```

Is there an elegant way to do this? I tried looking at fillna, but it doesn't have this option that I am looking for. It will either fill value 3 with 1928 or value 5 with 1853 (using limit=1), but this is not what I am looking for. The end goal is to do a returns series based on this data and when a value is nan, use the last available data that is not nan. So a new return series should give for spot 6, 1853/1928 -1 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create mask by [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html) and [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) and then use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.loc.html) and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a=pd.Series({1: 1918,  2: 1928, 3: np.nan, 4: np.nan, 5: np.nan, 6: 1853, 7: 1831})
print a
1    1918
2    1928
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     NaN
6    1853
7    1831
dtype: float64

print ~(pd.isnull(a) & pd.isnull(a.shift(-1)))
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
dtype: bool

a.loc[ ~(pd.isnull(a) & pd.isnull(a.shift(-1)))] = a.fillna(method='ffill')
print a
1    1918
2    1928
3     NaN
4     NaN
5    1928
6    1853
7    1831
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thank you. I actually was using a dataframe for this (even though I said series in the question). so I just removed the .loc and it works.